# Using jsx in jquery append function

Tags: jquery, reactjs

```
$( ".searchbox" ).append( '<input onChange=this.handleUserInput value=this.state.searchQuery type="text" id="typeddisabled" placeholder="Find a car ..." autoFocus />' );
```

The onChange and value attributes, how can they be set to jsx when using jquery append. Is this even possible? Right now, jQuery simply wraps quotes around the jsx.

Comment: Do not do it. React does all the dirty DOM manipulation job for you, do not mess things up.

Comment: I am extending a jQuery plugin, it needs to be in jQuery

Comment: Why don't you then do it with jquery w/o React? Although you could make part of your DOM controlled by React and another one by jquery this won't play that well together.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jquery in jsx or want to translate jquery in jsx language?

if you want to use jquery instead jsx, put the code after the  `render: function(){` and before the `return( //code );`